# Remove the subView inside Cell

Tags: swift

In my `ViewController`, I have a variable:

```
var shareButtonTapped = false
```

I want when I click the `shareButton` on the `navigationBar`, it will show the shareButton all of the cell, except the cell which indexPath.row == 0.

Here is the action of `shareButton`:

```
@IBAction func shareButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    shareButtonTapped = !shareButtonTapped
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

And here is the CollectionViewDataSource method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GiftCollectionViewCell

        if shareButtonTapped {

            cell.gift = gifts[indexPath.row]
            let shareButton = FBSDKShareButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 30))
            shareButton.tag = 1
            let photo = FBSDKSharePhoto()
            photo.image = gifts[indexPath.row].image
            photo.userGenerated = true
            let content = FBSDKSharePhotoContent()
            content.photos = [photo]
            content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.fantageek.com")
            shareButton.shareContent = content

            cell.contentView.addSubview(shareButton)
            return cell
        } else {
            cell.gift = gifts[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }

    }
```

It worked:

[image]

But I want to click this `shareButton` on `NavigationBar` again, all of `shareButton` inside each cell will disappear. How to do this?

Any helps would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `removeFromSuperview()` method inside your `else` block:

```
else {
    cell.gift = gifts[indexPath.row]
    for subview in cell.contentView.subviews {
        if subview is FBSDKShareButton {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Better approach will be to keep the share button always be part of cell. And  show and hide the button based on status of shareButtonTapped of bar button.

Let's say your button name is shareImage then in cellForRow

```
cell.shareButton.hidden = false
if(shareButtonTapped){
    cell.shareButton.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help.

Comment: Removing and adding subview is not a good approach unless that is the only option.

Comment: Nice. I have tried it. It's better because I have both save and share buttons.